# Proposing a tag synonym for org-mode <-- org

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are currently 36 questions tagged with [org](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org), all of which, as far as I can tell, refer to `org-mode`, which already has a tag [org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-mode) with 1,421 questions. Can we synonymize the two?

Comment: Sounds sensible. Let's just wait a couple of days in case somebody objects (could `org` mean anything else in the context of Emacs?).

Comment: I checked the list, and indeed they all referred to org-mode. Some of them were only very tangentially (if at all) connected to org-mode, but there was no other reason for the org tag to be used. I remove the tag from a few of those. The proposed synonym is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be no objections, so I have created a tag synonym that maps `org` onto `org-mode`.

One further possibility: we can also **merge** the tags such that we remove the `org` tag from the 30-odd questions that have it and replace it with `org-mode` instead.

Merging seems sensible to me (there are around 1500 `org-mode` questions by comparison), but please comment on this answer if you think it *should* or *should not* be merged.

Comment: Vote for *should*

Comment: Vote for *should* --  I don't see a real reason not to.

Comment: Okay, I've gone ahead and merged the tags.  Everything should be under `org-mode` now, and `org` is mapped onto `org-mode`.